# NameError: name 'simple_preprocess' is not defined

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to cleaning my data however I was stuck at stop words I try searched for the solution. After I tried the solution it is still error.

This is my coding:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
 
#importing Dataset
df = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')
 
#Creating the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
sb.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False , cmap = 'magma')

#convert all tweet into lowercase
df['tweet'] = df['text'].apply(str.lower)
df['tweet'].head()

#This function takes the full tweet text and removes twitter handles
def remove_username(tweet):
    remove_username = re.compile(r"@[A-Za-z0-9]+")
    return remove_username.sub(r"", tweet)

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(remove_username)
df['tweet'].head()

def remove_links(tweet):
    tweet_no_link = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", tweet)
    return tweet_no_link

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(remove_links)
df['tweet'].head()

#Remove punctuations
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace("[^a-zA-Z#]", "")
df['tweet'].head()

#Remove Short Words
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split() if len(w)>3]))
df['tweet'].head()

#Remove Hashtag
def remove_hashtags(tweet, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern,tweet)
    for i in r:
        tweet = re.sub(i,'', tweet)
    return tweet

df['tweet'] = np. vectorize(remove_hashtags)(df['tweet'], "#[\w]")

#Prepare Stop Words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words.extend(['from', 'https', 'twitter', 'still'])

def remove_stopwords(tweet):
    return[[word for word in simple_preprocess(tweet) if word not in stop_words] for tweet in tweet]
df['tweet'] = remove_stopwords(df['tweet'])
df['tweet'].head()
```

This is the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKOBp.png)

```
Cell In[28], line 59
     57 def remove_stopwords(tweet):
     58     return[[word for word in simple_preprocess(tweet) if word not in stop_words] for tweet in tweet]
---> 59 df['tweet'] = remove_stopwords(df['tweet'])
     60 df['tweet'].head()

Cell In[28], line 58, in remove_stopwords(tweet)
     57 def remove_stopwords(tweet):
---> 58     return[[word for word in simple_preprocess(tweet) if word not in stop_words] for tweet in tweet]

Cell In[28], line 58, in <listcomp>(.0)
     57 def remove_stopwords(tweet):
---> 58     return[[word for word in simple_preprocess(tweet) if word not in stop_words] for tweet in tweet]

NameError: name 'simple_preprocess' is not defined
```

I tried many solution but still get an error. I'm still confused what in the code was the problem...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are confused.  The error is absolutely clear.  You are calling a function called `simple_preprocess`, and your code contains no such function.  Did you not write this code?

Comment: no it was someone else I just follow her

Comment: We can't help you.  We don't know what they intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error occurs on the last line of your code, where you are
   calling the remove_stopwords(). You need to import the
   simple_preprocess function from the gensim.utils module to use it in
   your code.

> ```
> from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
> ```

2. In the remove_stopwords() function, you are trying to create a list
   comprehension to remove stop words. However, there is a mistake in
   the code. You are using the same variable name tweet for both the
   input parameter and the list comprehension.

> ```
> def remove_stopwords(tweet_list):
>     return [[word for word in simple_preprocess(tweet) if word not in 
>     stop_words] for tweet in tweet_list]
>
> df['tweet'] = remove_stopwords(df['tweet'])
> ```